# react firebase - how to get logged in users info

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a react app that uses firebase to login a user. What i need to know is how do i actually get the users details such as email address. I would like to get them into a variable so i can use them to populate a profile page.

I was able to create a Login system that create a user with email, password, username and location values. They show in the firebase database but how do i use them inside the react app.

From the documents i  believe im close with

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('https://website.firebaseio.com/web/uauth');
var user = rootRef.getAuth();
var userRef = rootRef.child('users').child(user.uid);
```

But im not sure if its correct or where to go from here.

Comment: That's indeed a reference to the user's data (if you store it there). Reading it is a regular read operation, see https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var ref = new Firebase("https://yourfirebase.firebaseio.com");
    var authData = ref.getAuth();

    if (authData) {

        console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);

    } else {

        console.log("User is logged out");

    }
```

This should get you access to the users uid.